# Github actions configuration for iOS project

Tags: ios, github-actions

I'm trying to build a simple CI/CD pipeline for [a demo iOS project](https://github.com/TungVuDuc2805/GithubActionsConfiguration) with Github actions. But it keeps getting fails with this error message

```
The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

Available destinations for the "CI" scheme:
        
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }

{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
```

Here is my configuration in .yml file:

```
name: Pull Request

on:
   push:
    branches:
    - main
pull_request:
   branches:
   - main

jobs:
build-and-test:

runs-on: macos-latest

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Select Xcode
    run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app

  - name: Build and test
    run: xcodebuild clean build test -project GithubActionsConfiguration.xcodeproj -scheme "CI" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=15.2,name=iPhone 11" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```

I've tried different command for destination for it didn't work.
Please help.

Comment: This action looks relevant: https://github.com/futureware-tech/simulator-action

Answer (score 0):

The man page for xcodebuild has the following description of the `destination` option:

```
 -destination destinationspecifier
       Use the destination device described by destinationspecifier.  Defaults to a destination that is compatible with the selected scheme.  See the Destinations section below for more details.
```

Meaning not specifying `destination` will allow xcodebuild to choose one for you. It will also tell you by printing log statements like:

```
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
...
```